# E11000 duplicate key error collection: happening.posts index: likes_1 dup key: { likes: undefined }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

try to add a new post to the database, one time it adds, and the second one gives an error
Post Schema is as follows

```
const PostSchema:Schema = new Schema({
    author:{required:true,
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'User',
    },
    title:{required:false,type:String},
    image:{required:false,type:String,},
    contents:{required:true,type:String},
    tags:{required:false,type:[String]},
    likes:{type:[
      {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User',
      }
    ],
        default:[],
        unique:false,
        required:true
      },
    createdAt:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
    public:{type:Boolean,default:true},
})
```

The post function is here

```
   request.body.author=request.body.AuthorizedUser.id
   let {author,tags,title,contents}=request.body
   tags=tags?tags:[]
   const data= await PostModel.create({author,tags,title,contents,likes:[]}) 
   response.status(201).json({success: true,data})
```

Comment: did you initially had unique: true ? if yes [drop index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)

Comment: Yes, but I changed it and  cleared the collection

Comment: So I just cleared the whole database and now its working

Comment: yeah the collection has indexes and that stores all the indexes, better drop the collection and retry or in your case the complete db